# how to render HTML elements based on JSON in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to render some html elements based on JSON data. 
I have a React class which takes these objects and produces a string list of divs; the values in the divs correspond to the first value in each object in the JSON.

This is my JSON:

```
{"spaces":{
"space1": {
    "0": 1.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
} 
"space2": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}
"space3": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}
```

and this is the class, which gets the JSON:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json"
import sample from "./data/sample.json"


class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data
  }

  render()
  {
    console.log(this.state)
    var df4 = df3["Spaces"]
    var d1 = '';
    for (var key in df4)
    {
       var host = df4[key];


       d1 += '<div class="'+key+'" value="'+host[0]+'"/>';
    }
    console.log(d1)

    return (

      <div id="Maps">

     </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Maps
```

This is what the class outputs, a string wrapping a bunch of divs:

```
<div class="space1" value="1"/><div class="space2" value="0"/><div class="space3" value="0"/>
```

I would like to actually have these divs returned on the screen:

```
return (
      <div id="Maps">
      // the list of divs should be returned
     </div>
    )
```

Any help, as always, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no arrays in your JSON data, so you'll need to convert it one. `Object.values` and `Object.entries` can do this. Then you can map as per usual.

[Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

In the following I've used `Object.entries` to get an array of key-value pairs, i.e. `[["space1", { "0": 1.0, "1", 2.0, "2": 0.0 }, ...]]`. We don't need to do the same for the sub-object since it is keyed to already be "array-like" (remember arrays are just key-value pairs of `{ [index]: value }`).

```
import df3 from "./df3.json";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: df3
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        {Object.entries(data.spaces).map(([name, space]) => (
          <div key={name} className={name} value={space[0]} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit still-morning-e6fgi]